# If I find a public web API am I allowed to use it in my application?

Tags: api, legal

If I find a public web API (by public I mean that isn't protected by any type of authentication) what do I need to do so that I am allowed to use it in my own application?

Is it enough to read and follow the terms of service, or do I need to do something over and above that?

Is it true that this is as legal as using a web scraper and that all search engines get away with that?

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'")**. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @gnat i just want to know if im allowed to use a public api or not?

Comment: Not necessarily, they might not allow the automated scraping of data (using a search engine for indexing is different to essentially ripping a database for whatever reasons). To simplify things and since noone can give you a proper answer in general: Ask the operator of the site. Maybe there's even some public API you haven't found (or that's not available for the general public) that you're allowed to use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpreting the terms of service for some unnamed web service.

Comment: ... you need to read the terms of service for the service itself and see if you comply with those. If you can't find any, contact the service owner.

Comment: @gnat: I tried to make the question clearer. Did I succeed?

Comment: @TomAu not quite. As an example, I can't grok relation between "read and follow the terms of service" and "all search engines" - as far as I know search engines are programs and hence simply can't read and follow ToS like people do

Comment: @Peter your use of it depends entirely upon the TOS that the service has and what you intend to do with it (it is one thing to ping a weather service for a personal cron job changing the color of a light in your house - quite another to make and distribute an app that does the same). This is governed by the TOS.  If no TOS exists or you want to do something that conflicts with the stated TOS you likely need to contact the service owner.

Comment: @MichaelT Post that as an answer and will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a lawyer and you aren't even saying which jurisdiction applies to you, so no legal advise from me.

But from a purely practical standpoint, building a product based on an undocumented API is a very bad idea. You have no way to tell if the API will still be there tomorrow. The one who made it can destroy your whole work with a single change to their API.

They might do this intentionally because they want to keep you out. After all, you are only consuming their resources without giving them anything in return. Or they might do it just because their own requirements changed and they don't even know that others also use their API. The only way to have any chance to get a warning in advance is to ask them if you may use it. When you are serious about your project and their API is essential for it, you could ask them to make a deal that they guarantee availability and stability of their API in exchange for money.